Macro to work through list of slicer options and print the sheet to PDF
I have an excel dashboard, the data within which is based off what country the user selects from a 'Geography' slicer. This code previously worked fine in another workbook, but now that I have copied it over into a new dashboard sheet (and changed the sheet name reference), it gives me an

'application-defined or object-defined error'.

The only difference between this dashboard and the last is that there is a larger number of slicer options, and the slicer is also connected to various pivot charts whereas previously it was only linked to one.
I've pasted the code below and any suggestions on how to correct this would be great.
Public Sub PDF_V4()
    Dim sC As SlicerCache
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pdfFileName As String

    ' Set the slicer cache
    Set sC = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_GEOGRAPHY") ' Change "Slicer_GEOGRAPHY" to the name of your slicer cache

    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MACRO INTERFACE") ' Change "PIVOT DATA" to the name of your worksheet

    ' Ensure only the first slicer item is selected
    If sC.VisibleSlicerItems.Count <> 1 Or sC.SlicerItems(1).Selected = False Then
        MsgBox "Please only select the first geography."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Loop through each slicer item
    For i = 1 To sC.SlicerItems.Count
        ' Select the current slicer item
        sC.SlicerItems(i).Selected = True

        ' Deselect the previous slicer item (if not the first one)
        If i <> 1 Then sC.SlicerItems(i - 1).Selected = False

        ' Set the file name for PDF export
        pdfFileName = "C:\Primark PDFs\" & sC.SlicerItems(i).Name & ".pdf" ' Save to "C:\Primark PDFs" folder

        ' Set the print area to the specified range
        ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:AR60" ' Adjust the range as needed

        ' Export the specified range to PDF
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next i

    MsgBox "PDFs have been created successfully.", vbInformation
End Sub

Essentially the macro selects the first slicer option, prints the specified range within the sheet to PDF, moves onto the next slicer option and does the same, and so on. Previously this worked fine. I've also ensured that options with no data are visible in the slicer as I assumed this could cause issues.

Which line is highlighted when you click debug on the error?

The debugger highlights this line:   sC.SlicerItems(i).Selected = True

Put a breakpoint on the line before that and check: What is the value of sC.SlicerItems.Count? AND when you get the error, what is the value of i?

Thanks - I've did this and the value of SC.SlicerItems.Count is 16, which makes sense as I have 16 geography options in the slicer. The value of i however is 0. I assume this should be 1 but not sure to make it hit this value?

The value of i is zero when the breakpoint stops? Or when the error occurs? It sounds like you checked the value of i before it actually started the loop. Check i only after you get the error. In other words, if the loop is 1 to 16, then there is no way it would ever be zero.
